# Unable to get records in connectedCallback using public property recordId but able to get records in constructor hook. How this is possible?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created a component
JS file(hookX.js)

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import getAlllRelatedContact from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAllRelatedContact';
export default class HookX extends LightningElement {
    //Defaualt Render behavior load html file component name
    @api recordId;

    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('Inside the constructor RecordId',this.recordId);
        getAlllRelatedContact({accountId:this.recordId}).then(res=>{
            console.log('Inside Constructor Contacts',res);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('Inside the connectedCallback RecordId',this.recordId);
        getAlllRelatedContact({accountId:this.recordId}).then(res=>{
            console.log('Inside the connectedCallback Contacts',res);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    disconnectedCallback(){
        console.log('Inside the disconnectedCallback');
        console.log('Record Id ='+this.recordId);

    }
}
```

ApexClass(AccountController.cls)

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    public AccountController() {

    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getAllRelatedContact(Id accountId){
        List<Contact> conlist =[select Id,Name,Phone,Email from Contact where AccountId =:accountId];
        return conlist;
    }
}
```

The output I got in console is
[image]

**How this is possible since  recordId public property won't have value while component is created or in constructor hook?
But recordId have value while component is inserted or in connectedCallback but we got empty response from class. How?**

Comment: Probably the contact returned in the constructor have a blank `AccountId` field. The class is `with sharing`, so if there are contacts related to that account you should check if the current user can see them.

Comment: @RubenDG Thanks, I checked the contact we are getting having accountId = null and also added null check in class and also without sharing. It is working now. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

@RubenDG
The contact returned in the constructor have a blank AccountId field. The class is with sharing, so if there are contacts related to that account check if the current user can see them.

[Zerox]
I checked the contact we are getting having accountId = null and also added null check in class and also without sharing. It is working now.

Modified apex class(AccountController.cls)

```
public without sharing class AccountController {
    public AccountController() {

    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getAllRelatedContact(Id accountId){
        if(accountId!=null){
            List<Contact> conlist =[select Id,Name,Phone,Email from Contact where AccountId =:accountId];
            return conlist;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
        
    }
}
```